# Unexpected array behaviour with use of sprintf in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am facing weird behaviour after apply `sprintf`: `list[0]` seems just gone away and result of `strlen` is `0`. Then I try to apply `strcpy`, `strlen` meets expectation and returns `3`. So my question is why `sprintf` will erase my `list[0]`, how do I recover value of `list[0]` if I insist to apply `sprintf`? thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char list[5][7] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };    
    char item[7];

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sprintf(item, "%-7s", list[i]);
        //strcpy(item, list[i]);
    }

    printf("%d", strlen(list[0]));
}
```

Comment: You need enough space to hold the null character at the end. Since you enforce a width of at least 7 chars, you need at least 8 chars. (Even that may fail for longer strings. Consider using `snprintf`, which guards against overflow at the risk of truncating the output.)

Comment: An char array of size 7 can hold a string of at most 6 characters plus 1 terminating null character.

Comment: @AtlasChiew:  you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 7):

Your code has undefined behavior because `%-7s` requires at least 8 bytes in the destination array: 7 for the left aligned string plus one for the null terminator. Note that if any of the strings were longer than 7 bytes, even more space would be required in the destination array.

This mistake might explain the observed behavior: `sprintf` writes 8 bytes to `item`, ie one byte too many, and if the array `list` starts in memory just after the end of `item`, its first byte would be overwritten with a null bytes causing `list[0]` to to be truncated and become an empty string with a length of 0.

You should use `snprintf` that prevents buffer overflow and make your array at least 8 bytes long.

Note also that `main` has a return type of `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char list[5][7] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };    
    char item[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        snprintf(item, sizeof item, "%-7s", list[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", strlen(list[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As other said:

At this line: `sprintf(item, "%-7s",  list[i]);` the `item` char array is supposed to be at least 8 bytes long to hold 7 characters + the end string byte `\0`.

Moreover `sprintf` is [dangerous](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf) you should use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: `sprintf` is not deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the `"%-7s"` that's causing the problem

Since the strings are 6 characters long, isn't it better to use `"%-6s"` instead? the problem seems to get solved that way.

**Edit:** Or as mentioned by @Welgriv in the comments, set size of the char arrays to 8 to have 7 characters

Comment: Or `char item[8];` before. But regarding the list array your solution might be more coherent.

Comment: @chqrlie No, i don't think i have enough repuration to vote.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other replies, the field width in *sprintf* mustn't exceed the length of the array minus one. The real solution is to not hard code any values which can be calculated from previous declarations. The program below shows a more robust version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))

int main(void)
{
    char list[][7] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" }; 
    char item[LEN(list[0])];

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(list); i++) {
        sprintf(item, "%-*s", LEN(list[0]) - 1, list[i]);
    }

    printf("%d", strlen(list[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Now, say you want to change the length of the character arrays. Then you only need to change the value 7 to something else and the rest will follow.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants